# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies when using appcompat_v7 and Facebook sdk.

Tags: android

I am using appcompat_v7 library and facebook sdk in my project and both the library have android-support-v4.jar.If I delete any of the jar the corresponding library is not working and  having both jars is not allowed.

What should I do? Kindly help me out...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conflict is due to different versions of the jar.

Make sure you have the update support library from the android sdk manager

Copy `android-support-v4.jar` to libs of both the projects. The jar can be found @

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4/andorid-support-v4.jar
```

Clean and build your project

Answer (score 2):

remove android-support-v4.jar from FACEBOOK SDK and add android-support-v4.jar as external jar facebookSDK properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add external jar (i had remove this problem like this )

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the dependency library from both appcompat_v7 and your project. To do that got to build path=>configure build path. Then select the dependency library and click on remove.
Add the support library by Android Tools=>add support library.
Do this to both projects.Then you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple

Just right click on your project as well as on the library project   >android tools >Add support Library.

This will update your support library to the latest which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is ask many times while everyone are start-up android development in learning stage.
I think everyone has same environment of android but they configure differently according to projects.

I had same issue while creating new project every time and i found solution on below.
I added library appcompat_v7 into project and remove jar `android-support-v4.jar` from lib folder of my new project and blink `ERROR` was gone.
Add `appcompt_v7` library project
[image: Add <code>appcompt_v7</code> library project]

Remove android-support-v4.jar from project lib folder
[image: Remove android-support-v4.jar from project lib folder]

Wow error was gone
[image: Wow error gone]

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix this issue is to look out for both jar files path. If you have "appcompact folder" in your eclipse then look into libs folder. In libs folder you have jar files.So, It's better to remove jar files from your application folder. Then at the time of compilation it will take jars from "appcompact folder".Don't keep jars in your app folder which leads to "Jar mismatching error". Error is mentioned below:

Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

**Path: /home/vinny/workspace/appcompat_v7/libs/android-support-v4.jar  (Keep this jar as it is)**

**Path: /home/vinny/Downloads/Demo/libs/android-support-v4.jar(Remove this Jar )**

Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Note : Remove  jars from this path "Path: /home/vinny/Downloads/Demo/libs/android-support-v4.jar" T(Application's folder path)

Answer (score 0):

Safdar Akrami is right, but also to do it on facebook SDK project!

Just right click on your project as well as on the library project >android tools >Add support Library.

This will update your support library to the latest which solves the problem.

if you have problem with the other projects that depends of facebook SDK project, you can fixed in this way:

1. Fix Project Setup
2. Add project "appcompat_v7" to build path of FriendpickerSample for example

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dependency library from both appcompat_v7 and your project. To do that got to build path=>configure build path. Then select the dependency library and click on remove. Add the support library by Android Tools=>add support library. Do this to both projects.Then you are good to go