# android-support-v4.jar error while integrating facebook SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I downloaded facebook SDK for android and added it to my project. Eclipse told me that I'm using 3 `android-support-v4.jar` files as shown in error:

```
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] Path: C:\Users\AjayKumar\androidworkspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage]     Length: 995624
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage]     SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] Path: C:\Users\AjayKumar\androidworkspace\Citizengage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage]     Length: 995624
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage]     SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] Path: C:\Users\AjayKumar\Desktop\facebook-android-sdk-3.22.0\facebook-android-sdk-3.22.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage]     Length: 758727
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage]     SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2015-01-09 11:53:00 - Citizengage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

So how can I use only one `android-support-v4.jar` that doesn't conflict with 3 libraries?

Comment: That is happens due to jar mismatch. find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346680/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies-when-using-appcompat-v7-and-facebook-sdk

Comment: Which projects? Copy to where?

Comment: remove the android-support-v4.jar file from the libs folder of your project.

Comment: It worked. I removed `android-support-v4.jar` file from libs folder of my project, added `android-support-v4.jar` of `appcompat`, cleaned it and it worked :)

Comment: ok.give up mark to my comment.

Comment: Yeah, voted up your comment. Vote up my question if you want